# How to define custom build variables in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, build-settings

In Xcode 10, I'm creating a C++ project that uses the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATH` to define a list of header include paths. One of the paths contains an environment variable, e.g. `${CUSTOM_INCLUDE_ROOT}/boost_1_xx_0/include`, where `${CUSTOM_INCLCUDE_ROOT}` is supposedly an environment variable to be set on each dev's local environment to give a root include path - the reason is that this root dir is of user's own choice, so different users can decide on different root dir.

However, in Xcode 10 build settings, it doesn't seem that Xcode is automatically expanding `${CUSTOM_INCLUDE_ROOT}` - causing the expanded header to look like: `/boost_1_xx_0/include`, and of course that causes compiler errors for `#include <boost/something.hpp>`

So, the question is: how does Xcode build settings reference environment variables, or is this possible at all?

Or a related question would be: if referencing environment variables in build settings is not possible, is it possible to define new custom variable such as `${CUSTOM_INCLUDE_ROOT}` to be `/home/username/globalInclude` inside xcode?